# Download a file from a webpage using python

Tags: html, python-3.x

I need to download a file every 2 weeks from a webpage but the file is a new one every 2 weeks and therefore the name changes too, but it only changes the last 3 characters and the first "Vermeldung %%%" are the same. After that I need to send it to someone via email could someone help me accomplish that?

This is the code I have right now;

```
url ='https://worbis-kirche.de/downloads?view=document&id=339:vermeldungen-kw-9&catid=61'
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector
import requests

parser = 'html.parser'  # or 'lxml' (preferred) or 'html5lib', if installed
resp = requests.get(url)
http_encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
html_encoding = EncodingDetector.find_declared_encoding(resp.content, is_html=True)
encoding = html_encoding or http_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, parser, from_encoding=encoding)
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

It gives me all the links I need but how do I tell the program which link to download. The link that needs to be downloaded is /downloads?view=document&id=339&format=raw

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get this link:

> https://worbis-kirche.de/downloads?view=document&id=339&format=raw

So, you could just do this:

```
import shutil
...
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    myLink = link['href'] # Assuming the myLink is /downloads?view=document&id=339&format=raw

myLink = "https://worbis-kirche.de" + myLink
r = requests.get(myLink, stream=True)  # To download it
r.raw.decode_content = True

with open(filename, "wb") as f:  # Filename is the name of pdf
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

try:
    shutil.move(os.getcwd() + "/" + filename, directory + filename) # Directory is your aimed (preferred) downloads folder
except Exception as e:
    print(e, ": File couldn\'t be transferred")
```

I hope I answered your question...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried implementing your code and I am just getting a bunch of errors, did you have the same problem? The most errors I get are traceback errors. I am sorry I am not really experienced enough to find the problem

Comment: If you have just copied and pasted it, I found one or two misspelling. Try now, it should be fine now.

Comment: i tried your new version and I get the error `   myLink = "https://worbis-kirche.de" + myLink
NameError: name 'myLink' is not defined` can you maybe help with this one too?